# Disable Google IME Shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, ime

I'm using [Google's Chinese IME](http://www.google.com/ime/pinyin/) (Input Method Editor). It has a shortcut -- Ctrl + Space -- which activates it, but I would only like to activate it via the mouse/ from the language selector interface. How can I disable the shortcut? I'm on Windows Vista.

The interface is in Chinese which is not my native tongue, so I can't find my way around it easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure on the Class name used by Google's IME software, but you can find it using AU3_Spy.exe which comes with [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com).

Then, use this autohotkey script to disable the shortcut:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class CLASS_GOES_HERE
^SPACE::return
#IfWinActive
```

Change **CLASS_GOES_HERE** with the class provided by AU3 Spy. To get the class using AU3 Spy, simply run the program, then hover your mouse over the window of Google Chinese IME. You'll see the class change in AU3 Spy:

[image]

As you can see the class for Firefox is MozillaUIWindowClass. If the program was Firefox, your script would look like this:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class MozillaUIWindowClass
^SPACE::return
#IfWinActive
```